# Lost Apple ID password and security questions and answers

Tags: apple-id

I lost my Apple ID password and security questions and answers. What do I do?

Comment: I'd rather leave this one open & mark the other as a dupe. At least this one is in English :/

Answer (score 2):

Regain access to the account by following the steps at [**iforgot.apple.com**](https://iforgot.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

These are some steps...
Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
In the Security section, click Edit.
If you already have security questions, you'll be asked to answer them before you continue.
 Click Change Questions.
    Choose your new security questions, then enter the answers.